# Search in list_filter results

Tags: python, django, search, filter, django-admin

I'd like to provide filter functionality in django admin list, but the list of available items to filter might be huge. I'd like to have select box, or better input field where the items list would decrease while typing. What would be the best approach?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to control the rendering of a custom list filter easily in my project. That should be enough to achieve your needed level of customization.

First, you have to create a custom list filter, let's call it `CustomListFilter` by subclassing `django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter` as explained in [the Django documentation site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). Then, you change the template used by your custom filter by setting the `template` class variable (`CustomListFilter.template`) to a template path with your custom rendering (the original template is in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/filter.html`).